# Python can't find numpy in Idle

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have an odd problem. I Installed Python 2,7 and afterwards installed Anaconda. If I use the **terminal** and type "python" followed by "import numpy" I everything is fine, no error.

However if I try to import numpy in the IDLE I get this:

**"ImportError: No module named numpy"**

Why is this? I thought the numpy was installed on the computer once and for all when I installed Anaconda.

Comment: Do you have different versions of `Python` or a virtual environment?

Comment: Idle belongs to a different python environment to anaconda. Try printing `sys.executable` in both

Answer (score 0):

When u install `Anaconda` it installs `Python` and other packages and might add `Python` to the `PATH`. Hence when you type python it opens anaconda's interpreter which has necessary packages. But you are opening `IDLE` of your previous python interpreter which doesn't have numpy.